# How to change text of coupon code the correct way (not editing core file)

Tags: magento-1, localisation, coupon-codes

I am a front end developer trying to figure out how to override

```
app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/CartController.php
```

So I can change the coupon code error text, can anyone please guide me on how I would do this the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a transltion CSV-file to your theme folder:

> app/design/frontend/theme/package/locale/en_US/translate.csv

```
"Coupon code %s was applied.","Your customized string"
```

Or for a specific translation

```
"Mage_XmlConnect::Coupon code %s was applied.","Your customized string"
```

*Note: replace `en_US` with the language code you need*

Comment: You got me started in the right direction it was: "Mage_Checkout::Coupon code ""%s"" is not valid.","This promotion has expired."
Thankyou bb!! :-)